# Detecting Thumb-2 instruction and location of PC offset

Tags: arm, thumb

i'm kinda new to ARM and i am trying to understand how instructions are interpreted/executed:

From what i know, on ARM is quite simple since every instruction takes up 4 bytes and it's all aligned by 4 bytes also.

The problem comes with Thumb-2 where their instructions can be both 16/32bit long. I've read that to determine if the current instruction is 16/32 bits long the processor reads a word (32bit) and evaluates the first half-word on certain bits [15:11]. If those bits are 0b11101/0b11110/0b11111 then that halfword is the first halfword of a 32 bit instruction else it's a 16bit instruction (I don't quite get why those specific bytes determine that). So an example should be:

```
0x4000 16-bit
0x4002 32-bit
0x4006 16-bit
0x4008 16-bit
0x400a 32-bit
```

Then the processor should grab from 0x4000 to 0x4004, evaluate the first half-word (0x4000 to 0x4002) and if the instruction is 16 bit then it just jumps to the next half-word and repeats the process but if the half-word indicates a 32bit address then it skips the next half-word and executes that 32bit instruction?

Also, i'm confused on where does PC point in thumb-2, is it still two instructions further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of us don't/won't know exactly how it is implemented in the logic (and there are various cores so each could be different).  But what used to be undefined instructions became thumb-2 extensions a couple dozen in armv6-m then like 150 new ones in armv7-m.

Think of the processor fetching 16 bit instructions, and sometimes it runs across a variable length one.  Just like other variable length processors, the x86 will look at the one byte instruction then based on that it may or may not need to look at the next byte and so on until it has resolved the whole instruction.  Same here, it looks at a halfword determines if it has everything it needs, if not it grabs the next halfword for the rest of the information.

```
0x4000 16-bit
0x4002 32-bit
0x4006 16-bit
0x4008 16-bit
0x400a 32-bit
```

the processor grabs 0x4000 sees it has what it needs, executes.  The processor grabs 0x4002, sees it needs another halfword, grabs 0x4004, executes.  processor grabs 0x4006 has what it needs executes.  grabs 0x4008 has what it needs executes.  grabs 0x400A sees it needs another halfword, grabs 0x400C, executes.

Those bit patterns were formerly undefined instructions, now they are part of the definition of a variable length instruction.  Just like instructions that start with 0b010000 are data processing instructions and to determine is it an add or an xor, you have to look at other bits.  These bit patterns define thumb-2 extensions then other bits in those two half words define what the full instruction is.

Why these bit patterns? You can think of it is arbitrary if you want, all instruction sets someone(/group) sat down and decided what bit patterns where going to mean what, no different here.  There was room in the instruction set space with certain patterns so those were used.  Not uncommon to add instructions later in the life of a processor family, take x86 for example.  Plus many others, for an 8 bitter like x86 or 6502 or whatever you can either consume an 8 bit instruction/opcode as your next new instruction or you take that formerly unused byte/opcode and expand it into many more for example you take a byte/opcode that was unused and that byte now means look at the next byte, that next byte could be up to 256 new instructions or it could simply supplement the first byte specifying registers or operations, etc.   No different here, down the road arm extended the thumb instruction set, some percentage of the instruction is consumed indicating this is a variable length instruction, but of those 32 bits there still remains quite a few bits to allow for a larger instruction with more options. (but losing the one to one relationship between thumb and arm instructions, all thumb instructions (not thumb-2 extensions) map directly into a full sized arm instruction).

Each core is different they don't all fetch a word at a time, thumb-2 extensions don't have to be aligned so a whole thumb-2 instruction won't necessarily fit in an aligned word fetch for the processors that do word fetches.  Think of the (pre)fetcher and decoder as two separate things, since they are, functionally the decoder takes 16 bits at a time in thumb mode, how is it specifically implemented?  I don't know.  Do they wait for two half words to be ready before decoding the first?  I don't know.  Is every implementation the same?  I don't know, would expect not.  As far as fetching goes they are not the same as you can see in the ARM documentation and I think at least one if not more the chip vendor can choose at compile time.

If you are coming from for example a MIPS based textbook and trying to understand other processors, this can be confusing, understand that those text books and terms are for understanding and vocabulary, pipelines are not that depth in general and you don't fetch whole instructions at a time in general (the x86 does not fetch one byte at a time, it fetches MANY instructions at a time).  Risc-v has even worse of a problem than arm and mips as you can have 16 bit compressed instructions, 32 bit instructions, and 64 bit instructions, the 32 bit instructions do not have to be aligned on a risc-v (nor the 64 bit) so fetching 32 at a time doesn't get you a whole instruction, the fetcher is separate from the decoder once enough is there then the decoder can complete.

I want to say that thumb is two ahead (independent of a thumb2 extension or not) so pc+4, should be easy to figure out though.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <hello-0xe>:
   0:   e005        b.n e <hello>
   2:   bf00        nop
   4:   bf00        nop
   6:   f000 b802   b.w e <hello>
   a:   bf00        nop
   c:   bf00        nop

0000000e <hello>:
   e:   bf00        nop
```

Yes, so two thumb sized halfwords ahead (pc+4) in both cases.  It would be significantly more complicated if it were two instructions ahead which is how it used to be to make it easy to remember.  If it were two instructions ahead then sometimes pc+4, sometimes pc+6, and sometimes pc+8 the logic would have to decode two instructions in order to know how the pc was offset for the first of the two, so sticking with pc+4 as it has always been for thumb mode is the sane way to do it.